# Why does this egrep command work in my shell but not in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, grep

The following command works on the command line in Linux:

```
egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#[0-9]{4}#.*?#.*?#.*?$" .
```

But when I use it inside a Perl script, it doesn't return anything. This is the Perl code:

```
my @rows = `egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#[0-9]{4}#.*?#.*?#.*?$" .`;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: not sure 'why' you should use it inside perl script. Could you rewrite it to readable perl?

Comment: @gaussblurinc, he's using egrep with the recursive option. It would be more verbose in perl.

Comment: please don't edit the question to remove the problem that caused you to ask the question.  or do you mean it isn't working for you even after removing the `$`?

Comment: Hint, `perl -E 'say qq(egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#[0-9]{4}#.*?#.*?#.*?$" .)'`

Answer (score 2):

`$"` is a [perl variable](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) and is being expanded inside the backticks. You'll need to escape the dollar

```
my @rows = qx{egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#[0-9]{4}#.*?#.*?#.*?\$" .};
```

I'm using `qx{}` instead of the less-visible backticks.

---

Another method, use `open` and pass each argument as a separate parameter:

```
use autodie qw/open close/;
my @command = ('egrep','-r','-i','-I','-H','-A5','^name#maria.*?#[0-9]{4}#.*?#.*?#.*?$','.');
open my $pipe, '-|', @command;
chomp( my @rows = <$pipe> );
close $pipe;
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I tried that but it doesn't work.This works: `my @rows = qx{egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#.*?" .};`    -- This doesn't work `my @rows = qx{egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#[0-9]{4}#.*?" .};` -- This doesn't work either `my @rows = qx{egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#.*?#.*?" .};`

Comment: @MarcosCamargo You'll have to be a little more specific than "it doesn't work." Do you get an error? If so, what is the exact error message? If not, what *do* you get? An empty array? An array containing one or more empty strings? Something completely different?

Comment: This works `my @rows = qx{egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#.*?" .};` and doesn't work `my @rows = qx{egrep -r -i -I -H -A5 "^name#maria.*?#.*?#.*?" .};`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I found my error. The files that I am searching were not properly generated.